# GlassFish running EJBs on different physical servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jms, jndi

I have a Java EE 6 web application running on `GlassFish` 3.1. The application uses 2 instances of a local `Singleton EJB` MySingleton. Each instance of MySingleton connects to a third party software through an API.

**MySingleton.java**

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class MySingleton { 
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;    
    private ThirdPartyAPI thirdPartyAPI;
    ...
}
```

**MySingletonManager.java**

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class MySingletonManager { 
    @EJB private MySingleton mySingletonA;
    @EJB private MySingleton mySingletonB;        ///Aargh! They can't run on the same server!!
    ...
}
```

Here are the constraints:

1. the third party software provider requires that its software runs each instance of `ThirdPartyAPI` on a different physical server
2. MySingleton uses an injected instance of `EntityManager`, needed for queries and transactions on the same `PersistenceContext`.

In order to satisfy constraint 1, I think that I need to access the Singleton EJB remotely: I will need to tell the application server something like "run mySingletonA on Server A, mySingletonB on Server B". For this I see that there is the possibility to invoke a remote EJB through `JNDI`.

In order to satisfy constraint 2, I think that I need to use GlassFish `clustering`, because the PersitenceContext needs to be shared across the 2 instances of MySingleton.

Unfortunately, I am not able to find any references on how to use the 2 tecnhologies together (remote EJB and clustering).

I am looking for hints or suggestions about the preferred architecture for this scenario, and eventually some implementation guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things...

First, if you're connecting to an external EIS system, the 'correct' way is to write a JCA adapter and inject an instance using @Resource. They're fairly simple to write, Adam Bien has a good example of writing a simple one. Think of an @Resource like making a custom Datasource for your application. It's actually pretty fun once you figure it all out. Writing any EJB that uses sockets or synchronization is technically not supported by the JEE6 specification.

If you do this, then you could install this adapter on both members of your cluster. Each cluster member can point to an external instance of your third party software. If either cluster member goes down, everything will continue to run just peachy.

But... if you really want to do things the hard way with singleton EJBs, you could probably do this instead:

First, get rid of MySingletonManager. Clustering is transparent, you're not supposed to know you're clustered. Second change your singleton code to:

```
@Singleton
@Remote
public class MySingleton { 
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;    
    private ThirdPartyAPI thirdPartyAPI;
    ...

}
```

It's important to understand that a Singleton *CANNOT* have state. If ThirdPartyAPI holds state between invocations, funny things will happen. You'll also have to put a round-robin connection code decorator around thirdPartyAPI so it will connect to both of your ThirdPartyServers. Finally, create a GlassFish cluster and deploy your EJB across the cluster. Inject it into your code like this:

```
@EJB MySingleton myIns;
```

This will automagically locate an the EJB somewhere in your cluster and give you a handle to it. Now, assume this all works and I didn't miss anything, you now have a concurrency problem, since by default, access to any EJB is serialized. You could add @ConcurrencyAttribute(NO_LOCK) but EntityManager is not thread safe AND it is also transactional.

Overall, Singleton EJB is going to cause you a lot of problems. Spend the time to write a JCA adapter!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Given the complexity of the topic, I need some time... By the way: can you clarify (eventually with some references) about "Singleton cannot have a state"?

Comment: Just found this interesting article about Singletons http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/singletons/ . Thanks for the hint

Comment: A singleton in a clustered J2EE environment will actually have one Singleton instance per node in the cluster. Otherwise, there would be a single point of failure... Hence, in a clustered environment, there are additional precautions you must take when putting state into Singletons, because they aren't 'real' Singleton. The easiest way to manage that is to avoid putting state into your clustered singletons.

Comment: @perissf on a side note, if you did find my answer useful, I would certainly appreciate an upvote or an accept :) :)